# Cartesian product yields a triple or a double + a single element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I'm currently taking a math course that has introduced me for the first time to set theory beyond operations like the simple union or intersection. In an assignment the following cartesian product was prompted:

$(\{2\}X\{1, 2\})X\{1, 2\}$

My initial answer was $\{((2, 1), 1), ((2, 1), 2), ((2, 2), 1), ((2, 2), 2)\}$ but after some clarification from similar examples I saw around the internet I ended up responding $\{(2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2)\}$.

Later in class the answer given as correct was the first variation (so I was apparently initially right, but I changed it). It sort of makes sense, but I was left confused. What is the correct answer here? And what could be a similar exercise that yields the other variation that wasn't correct for this one?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. But the other answer (with ordered triples) is also "correct", depending on the context.  This is one of those times when mathematicians frequently commit an "abuse of notation" by writing $$(A \times B) \times C = A \times (B \times C)$$ even though it's not true in general that $((a,b),c) \neq (a, (b,c))$. We think of both sides as $A \times B \times C$, consisting of triples $(a,b,c)$.  It's a bit of an annoyance in an introductory set theory course, where such things are distinguished, but if you take a real analysis course and object that $$\mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}) \neq (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} ) \times \mathbb{R}$$ you will get some bemused looks. It would be too time-consuming to keep track of the various ways of parenthesizing the tuples.